# Makefile: is it possible to have stem with slash?

Tags: makefile

I have these files:

```
 tests/prova.txt
 tests/mydir/prova.txt
```

In my **Makefile** I have a target like that for printing file paths (it's just an example):

```
checkf-%:
    echo tests/${@:checkf-%=%}.txt
```

If I call

```
make checkf-prova
```

it works!
But if I call

```
make checkf-mydir/prova
```

I get

**make: No rule to make target**

How can I call the target with a slash in % ?

Answer (score 7):

The stem (`%` sign) only matches valid filename characters, and thus will not match strings with /'s in them.  Having said that, pattern rules will strip directory names before trying to match, and then reinsert them when running the recipes, so:

```
p%.txt :
    @echo p\%.txt matches $@
```

will work with:

```
~/tmp> make tests/prova.txt
p%.txt matches tests/prova.txt
```

(notice that this is specific to pattern rules.  test/prova.txt will not match a prova.txt target, but will match the p%.txt target).  See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match for more details.